# Create new app to replace disabled App in Facebook Developer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, account-kit

My old Facebook app was disabled due to violating the Facebook Platform Policies, and it seems that it cannot be recovered.

Can I create another app with the same package name? What problems may occur if I do so, such as marketing or Facebook account ban ? It is not a problem if I lose the old data.